# Require some Large SaaS Advice for an existing platform

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, saas

We have a large SaaS product which is set up as a multi-tenant environment in AWS RDS with one read/write DB and several read replicas. DB reads are balanced across the RR's.

Working great but thinking about the scalability of only having a single R/W database.
Would increasing the R/W DB specification be the only way to cope with the R/W scale?

Don't want to go to the single-tenant model.

Any thoughts greatly accepted :)